# Export dataframe in R and preserve types

Tags: r

I am looking for a pair of R commands that dump a dataframe to the disk and that are able to recreate **the same** dataframe from the dump.

I suppose `write.table` is the de facto for export/import but it fails in the following example since it doesn't preserve the type of the columns:

```
df = data.frame('foo' = 'bar')
df$foo = as.character(df$foo)

typeof(df$foo)
# = "character"

write.table(df,'~/df.rdata')
df2 = read.table('~/df.rdata')

typeof(df2$foo)
# = "integer"
```

Comment: what about `save()` and `load()`. Not easily exportable to other programs, but if you're just reading it back into R - probably would make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TylerRinker said, `dput` and `save` are probably the most fitting.

...but `save` and `load` are sometimes a bit inconvenient in that you give `save` the *names* of the objects to save, and then `load` loads the objects back into those names.

An alternative is `saveRDS` and `readRDS` (yes, the naming is a bit weird!). They are a bit more low-level and saves a single object:

```
df <- data.frame(foo = 'bar', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
saveRDS(df, file='foo.rds')
df2 <- readRDS('foo.rds')
identical(df, df2)
```

Also note the use of `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when creating the data frame...

Comment: Thanks Tommy, also for pointing out 'stringsAsFactors' and 'identical'

Comment: @zoltanctoth Your welcome. Btw, you could specify `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to `read.table` too.

Answer (score 2):

`dput` and `save(objects, file="foo.RData")`  both preserve the column types.  Rdata object with save is probably the smartest choice and can be reloaded with: `load("foo.RData")`

Answer (score 2):

Use the functions `save` and `load`.

```
save(df, file="filename.rdata")
```

And then load it again:

```
load("filename.rdata")
```